# rsync --skip-compress option not selectively skipping files

Tags: linux, compression, rsync

I've been playing around with the `--skip-compress` option in rsync 3.1.2 and it appears to not selectively skip the compression of files with suffixes in the list.  As a basic example, if I transfer two files, a ".log" file and a ".grb2" file, I get the following results:

> **no compression**
>   sent 156,412,712 bytes  received 110 bytes  62,565,128.80 bytes/sec
>   total size is 156,374,300  speedup is 1.00
>
> **default compression, no custom skip list**
>   sent 99,482,854 bytes  received 110 bytes  10,471,890.95 bytes/sec
>   total size is 156,374,300  speedup is 1.57
>
> **default compression, `--skip-compress=grb2`**
>   sent 99,482,854 bytes  received 110 bytes  11,703,878.12 bytes/sec
>   total size is 156,374,300  speedup is 1.57

This suggests that the custom skip list is not successfully skipping the grb2 file compression.  If, on the other hand, I simply rename the log file to be read after the grb2 file, I see the following:

> **no compression**
>   sent 156,412,731 bytes  received 110 bytes  62,565,136.40 bytes/sec
>   total size is 156,374,300  speedup is 1.00
>
> **default compression, no custom skip list**
>   sent 99,482,869 bytes  received 110 bytes  11,703,879.88 bytes/sec
>   total size is 156,374,300  speedup is 1.57
>
> **default compression, `--skip-compress=grb2`**
>   sent 156,439,778 bytes  received 110 bytes  62,575,955.20 bytes/sec
>   total size is 156,374,300  speedup is 1.00

Which I believe indicates that no files are compressed when the first file read has a suffix in the skip list.  Looking at the `set_compression` function in token.c, I see that the `compression_level` variable is set to 0 when a file with a suffix in the skip list is encountered, but that variable appears to only be read once during the initial execution of `send_deflated_token`.

Am I doing something wrong, or am I misunderstanding the intent of the `--skip-compress` option?

Comment: Came here wondering why CPU usage didn't go down when using --skip-compress but did when using a separate rsync with no -z option. Has this been broken for 6 years?

Comment: On latest HEAD there's this comment in `set_compression` in token.c, "No compression algorithms currently allow mid-stream 
changing of the level" and the code that would make it per file is commented out with `#if 0`.